# How to retrieve duplicate data next and previous to a particular data from a list?

Tags: java

I have an list named duplicateDataLst which I got from SQL query in my java code, my DB table has all the duplicate data and their count.

Now I want to retrieve data which are duplicate to a particular data in DB table.
what I tried is

```
for(int i=0; i<duplicateDataLst .size(); i++)
{
  Object obj[] = (Object[]) duplicateDataLst.get(i);

      Long  id= (Long) obj[0]; 
      .
      .
      Long count= (Long) obj[12]; 
//Similarly other fields

 if(count>1)
{
  for(int j=i+1;j<(i+count), j++)
  {
    Object obj1[] = (Object[]) duplicateDataLst.get(j);
      Long  id1= (Long) obj1[0]; 
      .
      .
      Long count1= (Long) obj1[12];
  }
}
}
```

This way I am getting duplicate data which is  grouped by by sql query .But my problem is I am getting duplicate data next to the data only, not the previous data. For example if in a particular table 1-a,2-a,3-a,4-a,5-b,6-b when I go to 2-a i am getting 3-a,4-a as duplicate data but I also want 1-a which I am not geting. Please provide a solution ...thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can have your SQL Query getting you only duplicates, you don't have to handle this in Javascript, SQL is build for stuff like this.

A sample query (not knowing your Table design):

```
SELECT FieldData, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY FieldData HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This only gets you duplicated rows and the times they are duplicated.

Comment: that I have already done. I need to display all the duplicate data in jsp so i have to get all duplicate data in my java code

Comment: the reason I need to display all data is I am checking duplicacy based on few columns not on all fro example name fathername and city of 2 person can be same but category, subcategory , housenumber will be different. I think you got my point.